# High-Level algorithm for schema matching

Tags: machine-learning, matching

I would like to match two schemas coming from different sources (DB). For this I would like to try some machine learning algorithm to come up with a process to decided which column in a table could correspond to the same key. For example it's very likely that `FName`and `FirstName` should be a match and correspond both to the same "real world key" `First Name`. I would therefore do the following:

- For each column (key) extract certain features. Some of them may be based only on the key itself, others may use actual values of that key to generate certain features.
- I thought I will define features based on their data type, i.e. have certain feature extraction for strings, for numeric etc.
- Once I've generated all the feature for each column I can train a classifier.
- Once I have a trained model I can use it to predict for other schema if there is a match

Does the above algorithm make sense? There is one point which confuses me. I'm only interested in matching certain schema like core personal data. To training such a classifier I do need to have some test data. Is the test data in this case different schemas? That would mean I need many schemas about personal data which could be very difficult to find. Or how else could I train the model with just a few (say less than 10) schemas at hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### My initial thoughts

This problem seems easier to be solved by actually looking and understanding the schema from the DB's that you are using. ML is usually a good idea where the cost of a mistake ( false positive or false negative ) isn't too high.

In your case, a false negative (predicting two columns are not a match when they are) implies on not being able to run you application at all with those two features; a false positive (predicting two columns are a match when they aren't) means that the application will run with faulty data.

Both of those seem a high cost to run an analysis/application based on ML.

### If I had to do it

I would consider simple matching features before diving into a machine learning algorithm for 2 reasons:

- you don't seem to have enough training data
- you don't have a benchmark for comparing performance

So I would go for setting up a benchmark with simple heuristics so that you can set up you analysis/application, and improve it with ML as needed.

The simple heuristics I suggest are:

- similar descriptive statistics for numerical values
- most/least common for categorical values
- string similarity on the column names

Etc...

With that, you can start to have a comparison case before running a ML algorithm, which it self can have many problems associated with it, that are not related with the application you might be aiming.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is exactly how I was thinking about it. The simple heuristic you've mentioned would be the features I've created. But I need then to run a classifier to come up with a decision ln these features or am I wrong

Comment: If you don't have any clue about how to come up with simple heuristics rules, then yes, you'd have to run a classifier (like a simple decision tree). However I find it hard to believe that you have no clue on how the match features ('like title similarity has to be above 80%' or 'the mean should be at least 1.5 apart'). Will these simple heuristics be bad? Yes, but it will kick of things and set a benchmark.